# Determine OS using Environment.OSVersion

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

What is the best to determine the Microsoft OS that is hosting your ASP.NET application using the `System.Environment.OSVersion` namespace

I need an example for Windows XP, Windows Server 2003 and Windows Vista

Here is what I am trying to accomplish using pseudocode

```
switch(/* Condition for determining OS */)
{
    case "WindowsXP":
        //Do Windows XP stuff
        break;
    case "Windows Server 2003":
        //Do Windows Server 2003 stuff
        break;
    case "Windows Vista":
        //Do Windows Vista stuff
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following should work.  But why do you care?  Is just for informational purposes in logging or are you looking for actual capabilities being present on the target platform?

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5)
{
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor == 1)
    {
             // XP
    }
    else if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor == 2)
    {
             // Server 2003.  XP 64-bit will also fall in here.
    }
}
else if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
{
        // Vista on up
}
```

Comment: I need to generate the correct IE user agent string based on which OS is hosting my windows service

Comment: Isn't version major/minor numbers sufficient then?

like this:
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 6.0)

Comment: is there any way at all to differentiate between XP64 and Server 2003?

Answer (score 10):

Not a complete list, but got this from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304283:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|           |Windows|Windows|Windows|Windows NT|Windows|Windows|
|           |  95   |  98   |  Me   |    4.0   | 2000  |  XP   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|PlatformID | 1     | 1     | 1     | 2        | 2     | 2     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|Major      |       |       |       |          |       |       |
| version   | 4     | 4     | 4     | 4        | 5     | 5     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|Minor      |       |       |       |          |       |       |
| version   | 0     | 10    | 90    | 0        | 0     | 1     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Edit: Note, the information returned by System.Environment.OSVersion may be unreliable if the application is running in compatibility mode.

Edit2: I would recommend you just make it a configurable value in your application - that way your code does not need recompilation when a new OS comes out, e.g., Windows 7.

Comment: I agree with the second suggestion (Edit 2 note).

Comment: Trying to figure this out for Windows 10...

Comment: For updated list this page is useful [Operating System Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you dont have to be specific about R2 of server editions, a simpler alternative is:

```
enum OS { _2000, XP, Server2003, Vista, Server2008, _7, Server2012, _8 }

const int OS_ANYSERVER = 29;

[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "#437")]
static extern bool IsOS(int os);

static bool isWindowsServer = IsOS(OS_ANYSERVER);

public static OS GetOS()
{
    var version = Environment.OSVersion.Version;
    switch (version.Major)
    {
        case 5:
            switch (version.Minor)
            {
                case 0:
                    return OS._2000;
                case 1:
                    return OS.XP;
                case 2:
                    return isWindowsServer ? OS.Server2003 : OS.XP;
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            switch (version.Minor)
            {
                case 0:
                    return isWindowsServer ? OS.Server2008 : OS.Vista;
                case 1:
                    return isWindowsServer ? OS.Server2008 : OS._7;
                case 2:
                    return isWindowsServer ? OS.Server2012 : OS._8;
            }
            break;
    }

    throw new Exception("Strange OS");
}
```

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3138781/661933).

To be more specific your options are,

1. WMI, you will have to some manual parsing. Not sure if user privilege is going to hurt non admin users.
2. [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511176/661933).
3. Checking for `ProductName` at

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5) { /* vista and above */ }
```

Comment: I need to do different things for each OS version.  I was thinking a switch or if/else statement

Comment: Wrong Answer! It must be:
if(Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6) { /* vista and above */ }