# Identify the Operating System details in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, operating-system

How can I get the OS details using C# code in my WPF application?

Comment: You can find a simple answer accessing this link [I post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796103/4305317).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class provides [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) that can be used to obtain system information.

Answer (score 6):

You can get OS information from System. Environment.OSVersion [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [System.Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) It has property [OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Since I only have to care about non server editions, I do:

```
enum OS { _2000, XP, Vista, _7, _8 }

public static OS GetOS()
{
    var version = Environment.OSVersion.Version;
    switch (version.Major)
    {
        case 5:
            switch (version.Minor)
            {
                case 0:
                    return OS._2000;
                case 1:
                    return OS.XP;
                case 2:
                    return OS.XP; //could also be Server 2003, Server 2003 R2
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            switch (version.Minor)
            {
                case 0:
                    return OS.Vista; //could also be Server 2008
                case 1:
                    return OS._7; //could also be Server 2008 R2
                case 2:
                    return OS._8; //could also be Server 20012, Server 2012 R2
            }
            break;
    }

    throw new Exception("Strange OS");
}
```

If you really need to consider server editions as well, then your options are:

1. WMI, you will have to some manual parsing. Not sure if user privilege is going to hurt non admin users.
2. [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511176/661933).
3. Checking for `ProductName` at

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\
   ```
4. [IsOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773795%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3138781/661933). Of all I prefer this..

I provided a bit more complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18113873/661933).

Answer (score 0):

Using the registry is something that is possible for any application. In C# I have made myself a utility class for this. Note that Microsoft has changed the key for Windows 10+ (which this class is designed to already handle). The class should give you the information you need, I think:

```
namespace Inspection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Static class that adds convenient methods for getting information on the running computers basic hardware and os setup.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ComputerInfo
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the Windows major version number for this computer.
        /// </summary>
        public static uint WinMajorVersion
        {
            get
            {
                dynamic major;
                // The 'CurrentMajorVersionNumber' string value in the CurrentVersion key is new for Windows 10, 
                // and will most likely (hopefully) be there for some time before MS decides to change this - again...
                if (TryGeRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentMajorVersionNumber", out major))
                {
                    return (uint) major;
                }

                // When the 'CurrentMajorVersionNumber' value is not present we fallback to reading the previous key used for this: 'CurrentVersion'
                dynamic version;
                if (!TryGeRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentVersion", out version))
                    return 0;

                var versionParts = ((string) version).Split('.');
                if (versionParts.Length != 2) return 0;
                uint majorAsUInt;
                return uint.TryParse(versionParts[0], out majorAsUInt) ? majorAsUInt : 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the Windows minor version number for this computer.
        /// </summary>
        public static uint WinMinorVersion
        {
            get
            {
                dynamic minor;
                // The 'CurrentMinorVersionNumber' string value in the CurrentVersion key is new for Windows 10, 
                // and will most likely (hopefully) be there for some time before MS decides to change this - again...
                if (TryGeRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentMinorVersionNumber",
                    out minor))
                {
                    return (uint) minor;
                }

                // When the 'CurrentMinorVersionNumber' value is not present we fallback to reading the previous key used for this: 'CurrentVersion'
                dynamic version;
                if (!TryGeRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentVersion", out version))
                    return 0;

                var versionParts = ((string) version).Split('.');
                if (versionParts.Length != 2) return 0;
                uint minorAsUInt;
                return uint.TryParse(versionParts[1], out minorAsUInt) ? minorAsUInt : 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns whether or not the current computer is a server or not.
        /// </summary>
        public static uint IsServer
        {
            get
            {
                dynamic installationType;
                if (TryGeRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "InstallationType",
                    out installationType))
                {
                    return (uint) (installationType.Equals("Client") ? 0 : 1);
                }

                return 0;
            }
        }

        private static bool TryGeRegistryKey(string path, string key, out dynamic value)
        {
            value = null;
            try
            {
                var rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path);
                if (rk == null) return false;
                value = rk.GetValue(key);
                return value != null;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSDescription

[Alex Sanséau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47390306/13159913)