# How to check the OS version at runtime, e.g. on Windows or Linux, without using a conditional compilation statement

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2008

How do I determine what platform my C# code is running on? for example whether it is running on Linux or windows so that I can execute different code at runtime.

I have a C# Windows application that I want to build to target Windows and Linux platforms.

So far I have created two project files pointing to the same set of source code files. I then use a conditional compilation statement one of the projects called *LINUX*.

Where there are difference in the actual code I use conditional statements using the conditional compilation statement, for example,

```
#if (LINUX)
    ' Do something
#endif
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I don't really want to have two project files.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[**Editor's Note**: This answer was applicable before .NET 4.7.1, or before the Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core was released. The current best answer is [Alex Sanséau's to Stack Overflow question *How to check the OS version at runtime, e.g. on Windows or Linux, without using a conditional compilation statement*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116977/how-to-check-the-os-version-at-runtime-e-g-on-windows-or-linux-without-using/47390306#47390306).]

You can detect the execution platform using `System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform`:

```
public static bool IsLinux
{
    get
    {
        int p = (int) Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
        return (p == 4) || (p == 6) || (p == 128);
    }
}
```

From the [Mono FAQ](http://mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical#How_to_detect_the_execution_platform_.3F):

> **How to detect the execution platform**
>
> The execution platform can be detected by using the `System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform` value. However correctly detecting Unix platforms, in every cases, requires a little more work. The first versions of the framework (1.0 and 1.1) didn't include any `PlatformID` value for Unix, so Mono used the value 128. The newer framework 2.0 added Unix to the PlatformID enum but, sadly, with a different value: 4 and newer versions of .NET distinguished between Unix and macOS, introducing yet another value 6 for macOS.
>
> This means that in order to detect properly code running on Unix platforms you must check the three values (4, 6 and 128). This ensure that the detection code will work as expected when executed on Mono CLR 1.x runtime and with both Mono and Microsoft CLR 2.x runtimes.

Comment: So we probably shouldnt use `6` for `IsLinux`, then ;)

Comment: That was 2011, today the correct answer is RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(), as suggested by @Alex

Comment: Shorter: public static bool IsLinux => (int) Environment.OSVersion.Platform is 4 or 6 or 128;

Answer (score 195):

I found this recommendation on one of Microsoft's blogs:

> We recommend you to use RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform() for platform
>   checks.

Reference: *[Announcing the Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/)*

[`IsOSPlatform()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.isosplatform) takes an argument of types [`OSPlatform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.osplatform) which has three values by default: [`Windows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.osplatform?view=netframework-4.8#properties), [`Linux`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.osplatform?view=netframework-4.8#properties) and [`OSX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.osplatform?view=netframework-4.8#properties). It can be used as follow:

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
{
  // Do something
}
```

The API is part of .NET Standard 2.0, and therefore available in .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.7.1.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation/ for many more platforms.

Comment: Don't forget `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: There is also a fourth option now, [`FreeBSD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.osplatform.freebsd#System_Runtime_InteropServices_OSPlatform_FreeBSD).

Comment: Worked for .NET 5. :)

Answer (score 38):

.NET 5+ has the `OperatingSystem` class, so now you can just:

```
if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
    DoSomething();
```

Comment: Important to note that this solution is only for .NET Core.

Answer (score 19):

There isn't any such method, but you can use this method that checks it conditionally:

```
    public static OSPlatform GetOperatingSystem()
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
        {
            return OSPlatform.OSX;
        }

        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            return OSPlatform.Linux;
        }

        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            return OSPlatform.Windows;
        }

        throw new Exception("Cannot determine operating system!");
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
System.Environment.OSVersion
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.Environment.OSVersion` to check what kind of platform you're on at runtime.

Comment: No, you can't, because it returns true for Unix/Linux if you're on Mac, and true for Mac if you're on Unix/Linux...

Answer (score 3):

To expand on other answers, in cases where a Linux and Windows implementation of a feature are not compatible (that is, require references to libraries only available for a specific platform), you can also use an interface and have two separate assemblies, one written and compiled on each platform, with a type that implements this interface.

Then, based on the check, use Assembly.Load() to load only the right assembly (and its platform-specific dependency), reflection to find your type in the assembly, and Activator.CreateInstance() to get an instance of the type that you can then work with normally.

Comment: UpVote to you, all other answers are runtime checks which means publish folder would contains all dependencies - like windows.publish would contain linux dependencies and so on. Why there's no way to do that during compilation ?

Answer (score 1):

```
OperatingSystem os = new OperatingSystem(System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform, new Version());
Console.WriteLine(os.ToString());
```

Comment: Please provide explanation about your code that how can this solve the problem.

Comment: It just simply return you a string, the name of the operating system. I don't think so any explanation is needed so far.

Comment: the Vesrion() class represents the assembly version of your CLR

Answer (score 1):

Built-in static method: `System.Runtime.Serialization.OperatingSystem.IsLinux()`.

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to use `Process` to call a shell script to get the `uname`, as follows:

```
Process p = new Process {
  StartInfo = {
    UseShellExecute        = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    FileName               = "uname",
    Arguments              = "-s"
  }
};
p.Start();
string uname = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim();

if (uname == "Darwin") {
  // OS X
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This does not work for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I do this which works across:

netstandard2.0, netstandard2.1, net48, net6.0, net7.0

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static bool Running(this OSPlatform val)
    {
        return  RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(val);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
if (OSPlatform.Windows.Running())
    DoSomething();
else if (OSPlatform.OSX.Running())
    DoSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score -2):

With the help of TimeZoneConverter libraryable to map the google timezone with the windows time zone. This library has support for windows and Linux and most of the systems.

```
using TimeZoneConverter;
//Convert Google's Time zone Id into Standard Time Zone name using TimeZoneConvertor library's method named 'GetTimeZoneInfo'
Input : Asia/Hong_Kong 
Output : China Standard Time
TimeZoneInfo tz = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(timeZoneId);
```