# code to auto detect machines

Tags: c#, windows, perl, unix, remote-management

i need to write a program that auto detects windows and unix machines in C# on a network then copy a folder from a windows shared directory to the remote machine and gather how many processors are on the machine. I don't know of any C# functions that would help with detecting machines and their ips. I don't have access to active directory or have a central server for all the machines. I can create a perl program to run on the client machines. (also I'm not sure how to access windows shares on a unix machines) general guidance and code examples would be appreciated thanks

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116977/c-sharp-how-to-check-the-os-version-at-runtime-e-g-windows-or-linux-without-usi

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe that would require installing the mono framework on the machines which wouldn't make my boss happy...its not quite what i'm looking for thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) in order to discover network machines, it is client-less and with the -O parameter it will tell you if the machine is running a Windows OS or a Linux one. You can then use SNMP or WMI to retrieve the number of CPUs even though that requires machines to have SNMP or WMI installed. However with a client running on the remote machine everything would be much easier, expecially if you have to copy files.

Comment: thanks for the nmap suggestion...i only had one class in networks and we didnt cover that aspect..your right about needing a client to setup sharing and copying

Answer (score 1):

You have two very different questions.

---

1. Detect if a machine is a Windows or unix machine.

[`$^O`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5EO) will give you that in Perl.

```
$ perl -E'say $^O'
linux

>perl -E"say $^O"
MSWin32
```

---

2. Access a remote Windows file share from a unix machine.

Well, it's a [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) file share, for starters.

So all you really need is an SMB client. I quickly found [Filesys::SmbClient](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filesys%3a%3aSmbClient), a Perl module that seems to fit the bill.