# Is it possible to know a host is a windows docker container?

Tags: .net, windows, docker, docker-container

I'm working on a feature for a .NET application that requires to know if the host which the application runs on is a windows container. I could not find information 
 anywhere about this. It is possible if the host is linux but not sure if it is windows. Any helps would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this link [How to check the OS version at runtime e.g. windows or linux without using a conditional compilation statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116977/how-to-check-the-os-version-at-runtime-e-g-windows-or-linux-without-using-a-con).

System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform can be used for this purpose.

Comment: how do I check the .NET application is running in a docker container with this ?

Comment: @Chun This is not an answer to the question. If the container is a linux container, the code you have provided will always indicate linux, even if the machine hosting the container is MacOS or Windows.