# How to safely append to ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"]

Tags: c#, .net-core, process, environment-variables

I am currently porting a C# application from .NET Framework to .NET Core, to be able to run it on Linux. At some point this application starts another program in a separate process, using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. While this works well in general, that particular programm needs to be run with a modified `PATH` environment variable. This is what I did for Windows (paths changed for testing on Linux):

```cs
string directory = "/tmp";
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    Arguments = "-c \"echo $PATH\"",
    FileName = "/bin/bash",
};
processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] += ";" + directory;
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Unfortunately Linux uses a colon (":") as a path separator, thus the program produces

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games;/tmp
```

instead of the desired output

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/tmp
```

My question now is: How do I properly update the `PATH` variable in a safe, cross-platform way? Is there some system-dependent property to retrieve the separator character (like `Environment.NewLine` for line breaks or `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` for slashes), or do I have to check for the current OS manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.pathseparator?view=netcore-1.0) should be what you need:

```
processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] += Path.PathSeparator + directory;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a check if you're running on linux. if so, use ":" instead of ";".

```
int platform = (int) Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
bool isLinux = (platform == 4) || (platform == 6) || (platform == 128);

string directory = "/tmp";
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    Arguments = "-c \"echo $PATH\"",
    FileName = "/bin/bash",
};
processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] += (isLinux ? ":" : ";") + directory;
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

reference:
[Detect Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116977/how-to-check-the-os-version-at-runtime-e-g-windows-or-linux-without-using-a-con)