# C# .NET core on linux, GetSocketOption fails for DONTLINGER

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, .net-core

I'm running into a problem calling GetSocketOption in C# using .net core 5.0 on Linux.

Calling:

```
_socket.GetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger);
```

This throws an exception "Operation not supported".  Ok, so that option isn't support in the env I'm using it in.

The problem is that the exception closes (disconnects) the socket.  The `_socket.Connected` property is true before this statement and false after it.  Is there a way to check this in C# without risking the generation of a socket disconnect?  Is there a "safe" way to check socket options?

While writing OS specific code for this is perhaps pragmatic I'm looking for a way to handle this in a non-OS specific way, that is after all one of the draws of .net core.

**Update**: FWIW, I posted this as an issue and it can be tracked here: [GetSocketOption/SetSocketOption should not close underlying socket](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59055)

Comment: Take a look at this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116977/how-to-check-the-os-version-at-runtime-e-g-on-windows-or-linux-without-using

You should be able to check the OS family at runtime and conditionally avoid specific APIs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the OS version at runtime, e.g. on Windows or Linux, without using a conditional compilation statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116977/how-to-check-the-os-version-at-runtime-e-g-on-windows-or-linux-without-using)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25554

Comment: @EricMagers I would prefer to not have to write OS dependent code as the purpose of the code is to run on both Linux and WIndows.

Comment: @LexLi That is unfortunate, but seems to be the answer, perhaps I will enter a ticket since I would not expect GetSocketOption to disconnect a functioning socket.  
Thank you for pointing this out.  I suppose I'll have to switch to checking SocketOptionName.Linger or the LingerState property.