# .net exe in Dockercontainer

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I tried to port a .net console application to a docker container. The application tries to call ffmpeg.exe, I get an error? Is it possible that I can't run an exe in this container?

```
static void encoder(string inputFile, string outputFolder, string outputFileName)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(outputFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder);
    }

    var GetDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    // Part 1: use ProcessStartInfo class.
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startInfo.FileName = GetDirectory + @"/ffmpeg.exe";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    // Part 2: set arguments.
    startInfo.Arguments = "-i " + inputFile + " -q:a 8 -filter:a loudnorm " + outputFolder + outputFileName;

    // Part 3: start with the info we specified.
    // ... Call WaitForExit.
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("y");
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }

}
```

Error

```
OPUS-Encoder System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (8): An error occurred trying to start process '/App/ffmpeg.exe' with working directory '/App'. Exec format error
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Program.<<Main>$>g__encoder|0_0(String inputFile, String outputFolder, String outputFileName) in /App/Program.cs:line 77
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /App/Program.cs:line 34
```

thx

Comment: Are you using a windows or a linux container?

Comment: The error complains about `ffpmeg.exe`. The error `Exec format error` is a Linux error. You can't rung Windows binaries on Linux, you need to publish and call the Linux binary. On Linux, you can install `ffmpeg` through apt-get. The file won't have an `.exe` extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your docker container running Linux, but executable is Windows PE.

If your container is running Linux you need Linux binary not Windows
".exe".
You can get one [here](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#:%7E:text=ready%20to%20go.-,Linux%20Packages,-Debian%20%E2%80%93%20Official%20packages)

API for call will be same.

If you want to support Linux and Windows you will need to change path parameter according to current OS.
Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116977/how-to-check-the-os-version-at-runtime-e-g-on-windows-or-linux-without-using) about how to do it on runtime.

Comment: Is the call the same only without the exe at the end? I use a linux-container!

Comment: API is same. Only path parameter will be different.

Comment: @newby567 not just, you need to install linux version of FFmpeg into your container  and run it with appropriate command.