# How to get encoding setting of host OS (windows server) in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, .net-7.0

### What I need

Asp.net core app creates text files, whose encoding should match encoding of the hosting OS. This is because there is some legacy 3rd party software reading the files which can't handle UTF-8

### What I have

The app is deployed to Windows Server, that is configured to use Windows-1250 charset.

I currently hardcoded it:

```
using var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250"))
```

### Question

How do I get host's OS's default encoding, so that I don't need to hardcode or configure it?

Comment: You can try to [detect OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116977/how-to-check-the-os-version-at-runtime-e-g-on-windows-or-linux-without-using) and encode accordingly.

Comment: Looking at the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-7.0#remarks) section, `Default` is out the window, right?

Comment: @Max Encoding may not only depend on OS. The current default encoding for a given machine may not even be consistent over time (i.e. User could change settings to use a different encoding at any time).

Comment: Consider switching to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)…

Comment: You could of course make it an AppSetting. Then it would be kind of semi-automatic.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods: right, it can change, that's why I need to retrieve it. I've edited the "What I need" section with explanation why.

Comment: _"This is because there is some legacy 3rd party software reading the files which can't handle UTF-8"_ - wouldn't it be better to specifically set the specific encoding used by that 3rd party system? (Ignoring the fact that you would need to find _that_ out somehow, for now.)

Comment: I suspect they don't use specific encoding, they use the OS setting. I can't imagine anybody would hardcode "Windows-1250" for reading files :O