# How to programmatically tell the difference between XP 64 bit and Server 2003 64 Bit

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-2.0

I have a program where I need to display a different link to a different download based on what version of windows a user is running.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819962/80274) I am able to detect which version the OS is. Also using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1840313/80274) I can detect if I am running on a 32 bit or 64 bit version of the OS.

This would suit my needs perfectly, however I came across [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which states that both `Windows XP 64-Bit Edition` and `Windows Server 2003` use the version number `5.2`.

How do I detect the difference between those two OS's?

---

As a side note, I do need to send them to a different location if they are on 2003 64 bit or on XP 64 bit, here are the links I am needing to send people to:

- [Remote Desktop Connection (Terminal Services Client 6.1) for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7208)
- [Remote Desktop Connection (Terminal Services Client 6.0) for Windows XP x64 Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22465)
- [Remote Desktop Connection (Terminal Services Client 6.0) for Windows Server 2003](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21296)
- [Remote Desktop Connection (Terminal Services Client 6.0) for Windows Server 2003 x64 Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24717)

Comment: This will give you the string name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331826/get-os-version-friendly-name-in-c-sharp

Comment: Use `OSInfo.Edition` compare. ?

Comment: @Greg Can you provide a MSDN link to OSInfo [the only one I found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not have a `Edition` property.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724358.aspx   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11101/OS-Name-Version-Product-Type    http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/system/article.php/c8973/Determine-Windows-Version-and-Edition.htm

Comment: For the two people who downvoted, why do you feel my question "Does not show research effort, is unclear, or unuseful"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will set `wProductType` to `VER_NT_SERVER` for Windows Server 2003/2008/2008R2/2012, versus `VER_NT_WORKSTATION` for Windows XP/7/8.

You already know how to get whether the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit, so with a bit of P/Invoke (GetVersionEx is [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetVersionEx)), you should be able to figure out the rest.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use P/Invoke, you *could* use WMI, and take a look at the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class, which has the same information in the `ProductType` property. I wouldn't bother doing it this way unless you really *had* to.

Comment: I am already PInvoking to figure 64 bitness (no access to Is64BitOperatingSystem) so I will include it there. I will test it out and accept if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're programming in .Net:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3022k9x.aspx

System.Environment properties include:

- Is64BitOperatingSystem
- Is64BitProcess
- OSVersion
- ProcessorCount
- Etc etc

Comment: Please re-read my question. [Enviroment.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx) reports the same [major and minor number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for both OS's. That is the entire point my my question! Also Is64BitOperatingSystem is a .net 4.0 or newer feature. My question is tagged .net 2.0

Comment: You've got lots of options, including Win32 GetVersionEx() or the .Net "Environment" property.  The point is there's no one magic value: you need to use a combination of, say, "version" and "platform".  Or a combination of GetVersionEx() and GetCurrentHwProfile().  Etc.

Comment: Ok, then show which combination it takes to tell the diffrence between the two systems and I will remove my -1, until then your answer "Is not useful" (the alt text for a downvote)

Comment: My link should have been to the "Environment" class, not "Environment.Version".  Sorry if I wasn't clear.  One way to differentiate is "Environment.OSVersion".  Another is to look at the different OSVERSIONINFO fields returned in GetVersionEx().

Comment: PS: Here's a good link for detecting 64-bit OS in C#/.Net 2.0: [how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Comment: Please note that link you gave me I linked to it in my OP showing what I already was doing. Also, I meant to link to Environment.OSVersion.Version in my first comment. As to what it returns, AS I POSTED IN MY ORIGINAL QUESTION, it returns the same value for Major and Minor for both OSes. Now if you want to include a explanation (in the answer, comments) on how to use OSVERSIONINFO like [Roger did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15511176/80274) I will remove the -1. Until then I still feel this answer deserves a -1 as you provide no information on how to tell the difference between XP and 2003

Comment: Boy, what a twit ;).  Anyway: -1.  I think I gave you a couple of good ideas, and we can agree Roger Lipscome also gave you a couple of good ideas (including, failing all else, WMI).  Good luck!  PS: Greg's "OsInfo.Edition" is yet another good suggestion.