# How can I get system type by c# code?

Tags: c#

How can I get system type by c# code?
for example: 32 bit. (win 7 Ent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [IntPtr.Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size.aspx) property:

> The value of this property is 4 on a
>   32-bit platform, and 8 on a 64-bit
>   platform.

Comment: No, this will give whether the process itself is running in 32 bit or 64 bit. Processes can run in 32 bit on 64 bit platforms. Which equals to `Environment.Is64BitProcess`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
Environment.Is64BitProcess
Enviromment.OSVersion
```

And for `OSVersion` look in this for constructing OS name - OS version realations:
[Determine OS using Environment.OSVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860459/determine-os-using-the-environment-osversion-object-c)

and this contains the different OS name, OS version relations:

http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/08/17/windows-os-version-numbers/

Lastly, if you don't want to do all that code yourself, you could use this code (which will get you edition etc. but is not based on `Environment`):

http://www.csharp411.com/determine-windows-version-and-edition-with-c/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
System.OperatingSystem info = System.Environment.OSVersion;
```