# Listing a table of folders using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, listbox, directory

I want to mimic the functionality of the following image using Visual C#:

[image: Uploaded image]

This I know is not a `textbox` or a `combobox` or a `richtext` (Maybe).
I managed to get the add function, where I get directories and I can select them:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.folderBrowserDialog1.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
    this.folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
    DialogResult result = this.folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // the code here will be executed if the user selects a folder
        string path = this.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

How do I list them like in the image, should I write it to an `ini` file, or XML file, and then if so how do I list it in the box as shown.

I also need to detect the OS and have few default folders in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want, but the image shows a list with a string and bool value. So you can use something like this:

```
public class DirOptions
{
    string Path = string.Empty;
    bool IncludeSubDirs = false;
}
```

Then you can store your data inside a List<>:

```
var list = new List<DirOptions>();
```

To detect OS:

Please see this question [Get OS Version / Friendly Name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331826/get-os-version-friendly-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you @AlinaB I will work use this and get back. Thank you again.