# Get Windows OS name from XP and up

Tags: c#, operating-system

I am trying to figure out on how to get the OS name for windows 8. I am currently using the following code, but it is not handling Windows 7 or Windows 8.

How can I handle more recent Windows versions?

```
System.OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
Version vs = os.Version;

if (os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32Windows)
{    
    switch (vs.Minor)
    {
        case 0:
            operatingSystem = "95";
            break;
        case 10:
            if (vs.Revision.ToString() == "2222A")
                operatingSystem = "98SE";
            else
                operatingSystem = "98";
            break;
        case 90:
            operatingSystem = "Me";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
else if (os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
{
    switch (vs.Major)
    {
        case 3:
            operatingSystem = "NT 3.51";
            break;
        case 4:
            operatingSystem = "NT 4.0";
            break;
        case 5:
            if (vs.Minor == 0)
                operatingSystem = "2000";
            else
                operatingSystem = "XP";
            break;
        case 6:
            if (vs.Minor == 0)
                operatingSystem = "Vista";
            else
                operatingSystem = "7";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}            
MessageBox.Show("operating System: " + operatingSystem + 
                "\nOS Version: " + os.Version.ToString() + 
                "\nOS Platoform: " + os.Platform.ToString() + 
                "\nOS SP: " + os.ServicePack.ToString() + 
                "\nOS Version String: " + os.VersionString.ToString());
```

Comment: Here is a list of version numbers - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-7-in-net http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73000/Getting-Operating-System-Version-Info-Even-for-Win

Comment: You should use WMI. See the answer below:  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6331863/2550529

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from Windows Vista, the Major-Number of the release was `6`. Windows Vista has `6.0`, Windows 7 has `6.1` and Windows 8 has `6.2`.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx) for an overview.

**EDIT**

```
switch (vs.Major)
{
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine("Windows NT 3.51");
        break;
    case 4:
        Console.WriteLine("Windows NT 4.0");
        break;
    case 5:
        if (vs.Minor == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Windows 2000");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Windows XP");
        break;
    case 6:
        if(vs.Minor == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Windows Vista");
        else if(vs.Minor == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Windows 7");
        else if(vs.Minor == 2)
            Console.WriteLine("Windows 8")
        break; 
}
```

Comment: I know the version numbers, but how can i work these numbers in the script so it detects te verion.

Comment: Try to use `vs.Major` and `vs.Minor`

Answer (score 2):

You can get that using [`System.Environment.OSVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) and you're looking for 6.2

For Windows 8, you should check the following:

```
var os = System.Environment.OsVersion;
bool isWindows8 = os.MajorVersion == 6 && os.MinorVersion == 2
```