# To retrieve the operating system in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there any another property to retrieve the operating system in C# other than Environment.OsVersion because this property is not determining in case of Mac OS?

Comment: Is this an asp.net site?

Comment: [Get OS Version / Friendly Name in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331826/get-os-version-friendly-name-in-c-sharp) ??

Comment: @theedam since he/she has tagged mono, I don't think so. It might be an app that runs on a MacOs using mono.

Comment: You're using Mono, aren't you?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I don't think any of the answers could work on MacOS

Comment: @huMptyduMpty it wasn't mono when I asked =) think Markus added that tag

Comment: In a comment you mention "display a warning message in a page in case Mac Os". Are you talking about the operating system of the server or the client? It sounds like you're wanting the operating system of the client, then both Environment.OsVersion plus Tinwor's answer are both solving the wrong problem - both get hold of the *server* operating system.

Comment: Am talking about operating system of client

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this(according to Mono [Wiki](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aSystem.PlatformID))

```
string msg1 = "This is a Windows operating system.";
string msg2 = "This is a Unix operating system.";
string msg3 = "This is a OSX operating system.";
string msg4 = "ERROR: This platform identifier is invalid.";
OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
PlatformID pid = os.Platform;
switch (pid) 
{
    case PlatformID.Win32NT:
    case PlatformID.Win32S:
    case PlatformID.Win32Windows:
    case PlatformID.WinCE:
        Console.WriteLine(msg1);
     break;
    case PlatformID.Unix:
        Console.WriteLine(msg2);
     break;
    case PlatformID.MacOSX:
        Console.WriteLine(msg3);
     break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine(msg4);
     break;
}
```

If you are using asp.net you can use javascript for detecting the OS

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

Comment: But I particularly want Mac Os only because the task is to display a warning message in a page in case Mac Os.

Comment: Sorry but if you take a look to the mono Wiki you can see that there is only one option for detect a MAC OS system...

Comment: That's exactly what Tinwor has given you. Do you have a further question? The question you posed originally has been definitely answered.

Comment: when I use these statements it shows error in the "navigator". Is that a user-defined variable or some predefined property?

Comment: @user3512003 it's a js property