# Get MAC OS X Version number

Tags: c#, operating-system

I want to get the current MAC OS X Version using C#. There is a way to do it using a C# function?

I know the command sw_vers can do it, buy I prefer to avoid run a command if it is not necessary. What I need is a string like "10.4" or "10.6" or whatever.

This code:

```
Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
```

returns:

```
Unix 12.5.0.0
```

But not 10.X that are the version numbers of mac releases

Comment: Did you check the [Related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6331826/238902)? (They are found to the right)

Comment: I can't find anything there. The solution they propose doesn't give me the version name (10.8) that the sw_vers command gives me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Environment.OSVersion` and to get the version `Environment.OSVersion.Version`

The returned version is the `Darwin Kernel`-Version (base of OS X). You have to map this to the OS X version, see the table under: [Release history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29#Release_history)

Comment: But this gives me a number like 4.0.XXXX.XXXX,. I want to map then the 10.X number with the version name (if I can get the version name, even better)

Comment: Would you like to post your current code and result?

Comment: Yes, posted. Sorry, previously I was using  Environment.Version, not OSVersion. But this gives me 12.5, and the Mac versions start with 10, do not?