# How to get the Windows version to include in a UserAgent string

Tags: c#, .net, http, http-headers, user-agent

I want to send a HTTP request from my c# app and I want a properly constructed user agent string so that (at least) the operating system is well represented.

I found this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx#PltToken

that allows me to look up the correct strings for a given version of windows (my app will only run on windows), but surely I'm not expected to have a lookup table myself (what if my App ran on a new version of windows, I need to update it just to add a new UA string!

There must be some API I can call to get the UA string for the current OS, I just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by "well represented". [Most browsers](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) just report "Windows NT $NTversion".

See [Detect Windows version in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-7-in-net) and [Get OS Version / Friendly Name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331826/get-os-version-friendly-name-in-c-sharp) for how to obtain the Windows version. Basically:

```
string versionString = "Unknown OS Version";

var osVersion = System.Environment.OSVersion;
if (osVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
{
    versionString = string.Format("Windows NT {0}.{1}", 
                                  osVersion.Version.Major, 
                                  osVersion.Version.Minor); 
}
else
{
    // handle non-NT Windows
}
```

However, if your app runs on Windows 8 or above (8.1, 10, ...), you need to [manifest your app for that version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx), otherwise it will return 8.0 (NT 6.2). I suppose that with a newer Windows version you'll have to re-manifest for that version as well.